# Why is DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher not returning

Tags: c#, bluetooth, uwp

I have a method that has started failing, but only on one of my test machines, it works fine on the others. Here's the entire method

```
private void ScanBluetoothDevices()
{
    deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher("(System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}\")", _RequestedProperties, DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint); // ClassGuid = {e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974} includes all Bluetooth devices
    deviceWatcher.Added += DeviceWatcher_Added;
    deviceWatcher.Updated += DeviceWatcher_Updated;
    deviceWatcher.EnumerationCompleted += DeviceWatcher_EnumerationCompleted;
    deviceWatcher.Start();
}
```

On most machines this works fine, but on my Dell XPS15 running Windows 10 build 17025 the call to `CreateWatcher` never returns. I do not know how to diagnose this - can anyone see what might have gone wrong?

(N.B. the magic GUID is from the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enumerate-devices-over-a-network).)

Comment: Assuming you have **Exception Settings** set to **Break All** and is not catching anything, perhaps browsing the **Event Viewer/Windows Logs** could generate some helpful leads.